# How can I use ejs in my node application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, file-not-found, custom-error-pages

My folder structure:

```
├── routes
│   ├── userRoutes.js
│   └── authRoutes.js
├── views
│   └── index.ejs
└── index.js
```

The `index.js` file:

```js
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import router from "./routes/index.js";
import path from "path";
import ejs from "ejs";



//-security packages:
import helmet from "helmet";
import dbConnection from "./dbConfig/index.js";
import errorMiddleware from "./middleware/errorMIddleware.js";

dotenv.config();

const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(""));

const app = express();
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "views")));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8800;

//- Set the view engine to EJS
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//-DB configuration:
dbConnection();

app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(router);

//-Error Middleware:
app.use(errorMiddleware)


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

this is the `routes/userRoutes.js` file:

```js
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { verifyEmail } from '../controllers/userController.js';
import ejs from "ejs";



const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(""));

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/verify/:userId/:token", verifyEmail);

router.get("/verified", (req, res) => {
    const { status, message } = req.query;
    let obj = {}

    if (status === "success") {
        obj.icon = "✔️";
        obj.message = message;
        obj.class = "success";
        obj.statusIconClass = "success";
        obj.statusMessageClass = "success";
        obj.btnClass = "showBtn";
    }
    else if (status === "error") {
        obj.icon = "❌";
        obj.message = message;
        obj.class = "error";
        obj.statusIconClass = "error";
        obj.statusMessageClass = "error";
        obj.btnClass = "hideBtn";
    }
    console.log(obj);

    res.render("index", obj);
})

export default router;
```

I am trying to access the EJS file with the `https://localhost:3000/verified`. The error that I get is:

> verified:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If you reduce your code to a [mcve] (e.g. by removing all the middleware that isn't needed to demonstrate your problem) then people will have to do less work to reproduce your problem (and you'll be more likely to get help).